# JavaScript event methods inherited from prototype objects

Tags: javascript

I feel like what I have is correct code, but obviously I am missing something here.

What I am trying to do is create an event method in the prototype object of my constructor.  Here is what I have so far:

```
function Controls(but) {
    this.but = document.getElementById(but);
    this.but.onclick = function() {
        displayMessageTwo();
    }
}

Controls.prototype.displayMessageTwo = function() {
    alert("HELLO");
}

var Main = new Controls('testingTwo');
```

My logic here is that I am creating a constructor from which to build controls for something (let's say a slideshow)..  `this.but` equals the html element of a link called whatever is passed as an argument to the constructor.

In my prototype object, I define my method and then create my object.  However, this is not working as I had expected.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that when the event handler fires, the context of the invocation is not the instance on which you registered the callback.

Try something like the following

```
function Controls(but) {
    var that = this;
    this.but = document.getElementById(but);
    this.but.onclick = function() {
        that.displayMessageTwo(); // that is closed-in
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup.  This worked.  I must've have forgot that that the `onclick` event returns a new function all together with a different scope.  Is this the proper way to do something like this??

Comment: var that = this; is a closure by the way @SethenMaleno and yes this is pretty standard (in fact it is a must to understand closures (especially when dealing with closures that reference DOM elements as that causes memeory leaks)

Comment: I understand closures.  I was just wondering if using the `self = this` paradigm is a good way to go about it, or if there is some other way I should be doing it.

Comment: it is one way of capturing scope that is commonly used.

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong here?

You are calling `displayMessageTwo();` as if it was a global function. It is not, it is a inherited property on your instance. Usually you would refer to the instance with the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), but inside the event handler you can't. Create a variable referencing the object, and call that one's method like so:

```
function Controls(but) {
    this.but = document.getElementById(but);

    var that = this;
    this.but.onclick = function() {
        that.displayMessageTwo();
    }
}
```

As your `displayMessageTwo` method does not care about its context (does not reference other properties via `this`), you even might assign it directly:

```
    this.but.onclick = this.displayMessageTwo;
```

But I'd recommend to avoid that, methods should always be executed with correct thisValue. You also might use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
    this.but.onclick = this.displayMessageTwo.bind(this);
```

but it needs [additional code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) for older, non-supporting browsers.

Comment: Thanks.  This does work.  Is this the proper way to go about something like this??  Is there a different way that is clearer?

Comment: Yes, this is the standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I would think:

```
function Controls(but) {
    this.but = document.getElementById(but);
    this.but.onclick = this.displayMessageTwo;
}

Controls.prototype.displayMessageTwo = function() {
    alert("HELLO");
}

var Main = new Controls('testingTwo');
```

is clearer (assigning the function assigned to prototype.displayMessageTwo). If this doesn't work it may be because

```
 this.but.onclick = this.displayMessageTwo;
```

is evaluated before:

```
 Controls.prototype.displayMessageTwo = function() {
```

making it null...

Comment: No, it is not evaluated before.